# Appending list items to jquery mobile list using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have a list view in my index.html:

```
    <section id="dashboard" data-role="page" data-transition="slide">
            <header data-role="header">
                <h1>Trips</h1>
      <a href="#addTrip" id="createNewTrip" data-icon="plus" class="ui-btn-right"></a>

            </header>
      <div class="content" data-role="content">
      <ul id="tripData" data-role="listview">

      </ul>
      </div>
    </section>
```

I am able to populate this list from a SQL database using this controller:

```
$(function() {
  'use strict';

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",

    url: '/webApp/models/class.model.getAllTrips.php?action=getAllTrips',

    success: function(data) {

      //inspect the incoming data objects
      console.log(data);

      $.mobile.loading('hide');

      var dataLength = data.rec.length;

      for (var i = 0; i < data.rec.length; i++) {

        var item = data.rec[i];
        var tripId = item.tripId;
        var userId = item.userId;
        var name = item.name;
        var startDate = item.startDate;
        var endDate = item.endDate;

        var tripDetails = '<li><a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r">' + name + '<p><b> Start Date: ' + startDate + '</b></p>' + '<p><b> End Date: ' + endDate + '</b></p>' +
          '<input type="hidden"  value=' + tripId + '>' + '</li></a>';

        //push data into dashboard
        $('#tripData').append(tripDetails);

      } //close outer loop

    },

    error: function() {
      console.log(addTripPostData);
      alert('There was an error handling your request!');
      $.mobile.loading('hide');

    }

  });

});
```

I am now wanting to give the user the ability to add a trip using this controller:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#addTripForm').submit(function() {

    var addTripPostData = $(this).serialize();
    console.log(addTripPostData);

    $.mobile.loading('show', {
      text: 'Adding New Trip - Please Wait',
      textVisible: true,
      theme: 'a'
    });

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: "json",
      data: addTripPostData,

      url: '/webApp/models/class.model.addTrip.php?action=addTrip',

      success: function(addTripPostData) {

        console.log(addTripPostData);

        $.mobile.loading('hide');

                $('#tripData').append(tripDetails);
                $$('#activity_contacts').listview('refresh');



      },

      error: function() {
        console.log(addTripPostData);
        alert('There was an error handling your request!');
        $.mobile.loading('hide');

      }

    });

    $.mobile.changePage('#dashboard');

    return false;
  });
});
```

This works with a form i created. It successfully adds the item into my SQL database. However when it redirects me to the page where my list view is kept, i do not see the new trip. I have to click on the 'refresh' button to see it. This is no good for me as this is going to be a mobile application.

Could someone please help me. Thanks in advance =)

Comment: What is `$$('#activity_contacts').listview('refresh');`?

Answer (score 0):

What i would do is adding a refresh class on the element added, check for the element and when an element has a class of refresh refresh it, so you get around it. So if you want to include it in an other page refreshes only a part of the page.

Comment: Is it online or on a local server, if its online may i see it, and if its offline maybe add some error catching

Answer (score 0):

You may need to enhance the main content of the page, the listview will be included:

```
$(document).on("pagecontainershow", function(e, ui) { 
    var pageId = $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("getActivePage").prop("id");
    if (typeof ui.toPage == "object") {
        /* manipulate page navigating to */
        switch(pageId) {
            case "dashboard":
                $('.ui-content').enhanceWithin();
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

You may also move the `$.mobile.changePage('#dashboard');` inside the ajax addTrip success handler, after `$('#tripData').append(tripDetails);`